# native-run was not found on your PATH

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am developing an Ionic project but can't use commands like `ionic cordova emulate ios` I couldn't find any possible solution for me. When I try to run this command I am getting :

> [ERROR] native-run was not found on your PATH. Please install it
>   globally:

```
    npm i -g native-run
```

I tried to install it globally but didn't help. Here is my ionic info:

[image: ionic info]

There is now useful info similar questions in SO

Answer (score 1):

try with sudo as given below

```
sudo npm i -g native-run
```

if something wrong it will give an error in your command prompt. it will give detail for not installing but this code working fine at my side.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot